# EntityType Dual list Symfony Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using the Symfony3 framework and struggling with one of my forms... I have two entities;

1. Object
2. Element

I am trying to implement a dual list (multiselect) box. I have succeeded untill the image below: (So i got the front-end going on, it's something... :S) 
[image]

With the code below i can only choose to select (or de-select) ALL "Element" entities. Only then the form is submitted and persisted (succesfully!).

BUT When i **select** only 1 "Element" i can submit the form but i get an error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO objects_elements (object_id, element_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [3, 1]:

When i **deselect** 1 "Element" i get no error but the element stays in the selected box.

This is my code:

```
// ...
class Object {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Element", inversedBy="objects")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="objects_elements")
 */
protected $elements;

// ...

}
```

---

```
class Element {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Object", mappedBy="elements")
 */
private $objects;
```

My FormType looks like this

```
class ObjectType extends AbstractType {

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
            ->add('elements', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Element',
                'multiple' => true,
                'empty_data'  => null,
                'required'    => false,
            ))
    ;
}
```

My controller (I only will post the editAction) looks like this:

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Object entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="object_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Object $object) {
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($object);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ObjectType', $object);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($object);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('object_edit', array('id' => $object->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('object/edit.html.twig', array(
                'object' => $object,
                'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
                'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: I suspect you need to use http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thanks, but in this case i don't want that. Thats something totally different. I implemented that in a different situation, but doesn't fit my needs in this situation.

Comment: From my understanding, when you deselet an element, you need a kind of `RemoveElement(Entity $entity)` method to be applied on the Object when form is submitted.